# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar los caracteres de un string en base a condiciones?

Tags: java

Estuve investigando un poco acerca de como remplazar caracteres en un string, pero son dirigidos a otros aspectos, como el hecho de remplazar letras exactas por otra letra exacta. La pregunta es, ¿Cómo seria la estructura para que de una cadena de texto tomemos ciertas partes de la misma y las modifiquemos?

En mi caso me gustaría realizar lo siguiente:

Digamos que un usuario ingresa en una variable String un texto como el siguiente

*"**El día de hoy salí a pasear en mi bici a la playa**"*

Y quiero que modifique cada palabra del String que cumpla con la característica de tener cuatro letras y dichos caracteres se cambien por asteriscos, para que de como resultado lo siguiente

*"**El día de hoy **** a pasear en mi **** a la playa**"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      String[]lineas=sc.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
      String resp="";
      for(int i=0;i<lineas.length;i++){
        if(lineas[i].length()==4){
            resp+=(i<lineas.length-1?("**** "):"****");
        }
        else{
            resp+=(i<lineas.length-1?(lineas[i]+" "):lineas[i]);
        }
      }
      System.out.print(resp);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por paso

Por lo que entendí de tu escrito deberías obtener cada palabra de la oración para eso usa esto

```
var palabras = string.Split(' ').ToList();
```

Esto almacena en una lista cada palabra de tu oración separando cada palabra mediante los espacios en blanco qué hay entre ellas

Comment: Sólo faltaría añadir que quiere que cada palabra de cuatro caracteres se reemplace por ****

Answer (score 0):

Para eso se utiliza el método `String.replaceAll()` que permite usar una expresión regular como la *aguja* a buscar (y reemplazar) en el pajar.

[Ejemplo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: Gracias x la corrección, @franqo.... ree_n_plazar. Me dolieron los ojos :D